# Avoid serialization of a property name in json.net

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

How to avoid a property name during serialization? Below an example

```
public class A {      
public List<object> Values { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
}

A a = new A();
a.Name = "Numbers"
a.Values = new List<object>();
a.Values.Add(1);
a.Values.Add(2);
a.Values.Add(3);
a.Values.Add(4);

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { a });
```

After serialization, result includes a property names "values"

```
{
  "a": {
    "values": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4
    ],
    "name": "Numbers"
  }
}
```

but, I need the following

```
{
  "a": [
      1,
      2,
      3,
      4
   ],
"name": "Numbers"
}
```

Comment: So where is your serialization code?

Comment: What does your full class look like?  We still need to see your serialization code

Comment: I've put serialization code here, and I also updated a class

Answer (score 2):

Just serialize `a.Values`;

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a.Values);
```

Comment: Collection is inside of my custom class, it has another properties as well. So, I need the whole class to be serialized along with collection members, but without a property names.

Comment: @user3580877 edit your question to include more detail.  You never mention anything about other properties.

Comment: @user3580877 What you are asking for makes no sense and it is not even valid JSON

Comment: You can't do that. You should provide "key" for per element inside json.

Comment: let me update the question, json is valid, checked with https://www.json-generator.com/#

Comment: Is there any way to avoid it in case of collection?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple mistakes in your code.

First, if you want this class:

```
public class A 
{      
    public List<object> Values { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To serialize to this json:

```
{
    "a": [
           1, 
           2, 
           3, 
           4
         ],
    "name": "Numbers"
}
```

You are gonna have a bad time.  Just look at the structure, they are not 1-1.

You need to change your class, make sure you name it something meaningful (a class of a single letter is a really bad idea).

```
public class SomeClass
{   
    [JsonProperty("a")]
    public List<object> Values { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You notice the `[JsonProperty()]` attribute above?  That tells the serializer that this property should serialize with the defined name.  That way you can have a *meaningful* property name ("Values") while in code, and still have the json serialize the way you want it to ("a").

The second problem is when you serialize you are creating a new anonymous object with a property of the class you instance you created.  Which will again mess your structure up.  Change your serialization code to just serialize the object instance:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someInstanceOfYourClass);
```

My above changes should give you json that looks like this:

```
{
    "a": [
           1, 
           2, 
           3, 
           4
         ],
    "name": "Numbers"
}
```

I have made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bt5UNd) that will demonstrate.

Comment: Your two JSON examples are the same here.